# CKEditor Adding Extra Classes To Widget

Tags: ckeditor

I've created a CKEditor widget to allow a user to input a section of text into a colored box once it is output to a report. My code is almost exactly like [the simplebox example on the CK site](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1-section-full-source-code)

While I can get the widget to work and add the correct classes, 'simplebox-title' etc, it is also adding a ton of extra wrapper classes, data tags, and even an img (for the move button) when I save it into the database. So instead of having a clean:

```
<div class="simplebox-title"></div>
```

I end up with about 4 lines of code like:

```
<div data-cke-widget-id="0" data-cke-display-name="div" class="cke_widget_wrapper cke_widget_block" data-cke-filter="off".....etc>
```

All of this is going into the database. It even transfers the image of the "+" sign to move the div around. I don't want any of this as it comes through from the database into the report page.

I'm sure I'm missing something (probably obvious), but I can't find it.  And blowing up the DB + having that move button won't work on a report.

I'm using PHP/Laravel, mysql, standard (not floating) CKEditor, CKEditor Save plugin.

Any help?

Comment: Source code? I'm assuming you are using the save plugin, not widget?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the save plugin, thank you for clarifying.  The issue arises from making the widget editable.  If not editable, the extra tags don't show up.  I suppose it makes sense to have them so JS can figure out what to allow... but it would be nice to be able to turn it off upon saving.  Source code is at the link above - same code, I just have a wrapper using the save plugin, which works fine for all other input.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to make this work.  If the cke_ class wrappers are stripped, there's no way for CKEditor to know that it needs to make the area editable or movable.  I've removed all this widget code and just added a command that has the editor .insertHtml().  This does what I need almost as well - just can't move it.

Comment: The problem is the way that you're reading the data from the editor. If you use its API then it will strip out all the elements and attributes related to the widget, but if you're accessing directly the contents then you get all the extra stuff

Comment: I have done this before, and I was able to deal with all this using upcasts/downcasts.